# Why isn't the insert procedure working ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, datatable, ado

The datatable:
[image: The adapter table]

The Procedure:
[image: The Procedure]

I don't know why isn't the Procedure working , but here is the code

```
 //The datatable

      DS_USER.USER_SELECTDataTable UDT = new DS_USER.USER_SELECTDataTable();
      DS_USERTableAdapters.USER_SELECTTableAdapter UAdapter = new DS_USERTableAdapters.USER_SELECTTableAdapter();

...

...
   UAdapter.insert(txtname.Text, txtsname.Text, txtadd.Text, txtcity.Text, txtppin.Text, txtmo.Text, txtemail.Text, txtpass.Text);
```

It's a simple insert command why is it not working?

Comment: Pop a debug point on the `UAdapter.insert(` line, what are the values for each `*.text` property you are passing?

Comment: @MarkCooper How do i get a debug point?

Comment: By debug point, Mark meant a breakpoint, which is a signal to the IDE to stop execution of your app at a specific point so that you can inspect the values and step through the code line by line. You can learn more about how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019). It's an invaluable tool that all programmers need to master.